# Did anyone publicly call Jesus a glutton?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, gospel-of-matthew

We see Jesus saying in Mtt 11:18-19 (NRSVCE):

> For John came neither eating nor drinking, and they say, ‘He has a demon’;  the Son of Man came eating and drinking, and they say, ‘Look, a glutton and a drunkard, a friend of tax collectors and sinners!’

One does not,  in fact, come across  a reference in the Gospels, in which Jesus'adversaries including the Pharisee and the Sadducee accuse him of being a glutton. Is it that they talked about it among themselves, and Jesus in his divine nature, came to know of it ? Or, is it that Jesus foresaw their thought, and made it  public while they were watching ? My question therefore, is: According to Catholic scholars, did anyone publicly call Jesus a glutton ?

Comment: Please learn to fix your formatting. You can't start a paragraph with spaces like that.

Comment: I don't understand the point of this question. Are you accusing Jesus of lying? The Gospels only record a tiny fraction of Jesus's life. Why would you doubt this??

Comment: We see Jesus defending his disciples against the question of fasting, as put by John's disciples, in Mtt 9:14-15 :  Then John’s disciples came and asked him, “How is it that we and the Pharisees fast often, but your disciples do not fast?” Jesus answered, “How can the guests of the bridegroom mourn while he is with them? The time will come when the bridegroom will be taken from them; then they will fast. ".   One feels that John's disciples were indirectly comparing Jesus with John the Baptist , in so far eating and fasting were concerned, .

Comment: Yes, people said various things about Jesus at various times. That gives no reason to you to think Jesus was lying here.

Comment: Jesus in deed knew the hearts of his audience.  See for instance, Mk 2:6-8 : "Now some teachers of the law were sitting there, thinking to themselves,  “Why does this fellow talk like that? He’s blaspheming! Who can forgive sins but God alone?” Immediately Jesus knew in his spirit that this was what they were thinking in their hearts, and he said to them, “Why are you thinking these things? ".  So, some one would have thought by himself, or had a secret discussion that Jesus was a glutton, and Jesus was able to read the thought/secret discussion.  That does not translate into lying.

Comment: So is your question more of whether some said that to his face, or whether they said it behind his back? Well the text just doesn't say. Scholars can't produce certainty for questions like that out of silence.